# Is there any event to indicate that the uploaded file has been written with CollectionFS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor

In my Meteor + Angular + CollectionFS project I have this function :

```
$scope.upload = function(file) {
    Images.insert(file._file, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            $scope.project.teaserImg = "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id;
            $scope.$apply(); //Force the refresh
        }
    });
};
```

The problem is I have 503 error on my `<img ng-src="{{project.teaserImg}}"/>` in my template because the file has not finished to upload yet. If I don't force the refresh and wait a few second, it works.

So I am looking for event like onProgress, onFileWrtiten, etc... to handle this.I can't find any detailled doc in [the repo](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually **FSCollection** have a Package named [Meteor-cfs-ui](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-ui), and it have a progress bar.

So First add it

```
meteor add cfs:ui
```

So with this package, you can do this on the `<template>`, this is just a **HTML** solution

```
{{#each images}}
  {{#unless this.isUploaded}}
  {{> FS.UploadProgressBar}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

If you don't want to make the work on the HTML side, also there is a **JavaScript** Solution, with 2 posible options client side or server side, choose what you think it suits better.

**Client side Solution**, here you have 2 methods `fileObj.isUploaded` and `fileObj.hasStored` (There is not Documentation on the [README](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/555) for this since the creators of the package clean it few days ago.)

```
    var fileId; //store the current id of the file

        $scope.upload = function(file) {
            Images.insert(file._file, function (err, fileObj) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {
                    fileId = result._id //get the id of the upload file
                    $scope.project.teaserImg = "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id;
                    $scope.$apply(); //Force the refresh
                }
            });
        };
    //Some Reactive tracker to check when the file its ready
   Tracker.autorun(function (computation) {
       var fileObj = Images.findOne(fileId);
       if (fileObj.hasStored('yourStoreName')) {
          computation.stop();
       }
    });
```

or **Server side solution**, CFS has 3 events on the server side, `stored`,`uploaded` and `error`.

```
    Images.on('stored', function (fileObj, storeName) {
      console.log("The " + fileObj + " with the _id " + fileObj._id " + just get stored")
    });
    Images.on('uploaded', function (fileObj) {
      console.log("The " + fileObj + " with the _id " + fileObj._id " + just get uploaded")
    });
```

**UPLOAD USER SOLUTION**

```
var fileId; //store the id of the uploaded file 
$scope.upload = function(file){ 
Images.insert(file._file, function (err,fileObj) { 
      if (err) console.log(err); 
      else { fileId = fileObj._id 
     } 
   }); 
};
```

and The Tracker

```
Tracker.autorun(function (computation) { 
    var fileObj = Images.findOne(fileId); 
  if (fileObj) { $scope.project.teaserImg = "/cfs/files/images/" + fileId;      $scope.$apply(); 
computation.stop();
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thx Ethaan. Could you past the final code in your JS client side solution :

`var fileId; //store the id of the uploaded file
$scope.upload = function(file) {
 Images.insert(file._file, function (err, fileObj) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
   fileId = fileObj._id
  }
 });
};`
and
`Tracker.autorun(function (computation) {
 var fileObj =  Images.findOne(fileId);
 if (fileObj) {
  $scope.project.teaserImg = "/cfs/files/images/" + fileId;
  $scope.$apply();
  computation.stop();
 }
});`

Comment: Downvote because person is asking about a Meteor + Angular solution and yours is not. Or at least not complete (didn't work). Check my amalgamated solution below which did work for me. It was inspired on your answer, though. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

I am running in a similar issue while using Angular + Meteor so rules out using Blaze for the CFS:UI package progress bar.

I am not uploading images, but xmlFiles. Same principal though.

So I was very interested in Ethaan's solution but couldn't get it to work. After looking in the CFS:UI js files and rethink the matter I came up with a working version. 
I doubt the Ethaan is using Angular + Meteor because she reference the Tracker object.
Anyway, to get this to work I had to add three things:
1) make sure there is an active subscription to your file collection
2) use the $scope.$meteorAutorun function
3) set the fileId in the scope and use `getReactively` to get the file ID to trigger the autorun to reRun.

So the final solution was this (in Coffeescript, use http://js2.coffee/ to convert):

```
# create subscription
$scope.xmlFiles = $meteor.collectionFS(XmlFiles, false, XmlFiles).subscribe('xmlFiles');

# my file handler, linked to submit button
$scope.uploadFile = ->
  $scope.fileId = null
  # uploadForm.xmlFile is the actual input:file from my form
  XmlFiles.insert uploadForm.xmlFile.files[0], (err, fileObj) ->

    if fileObj._id
      $scope.fileId = fileObj._id

  $scope.$meteorAutorun (computation) ->
    fileId = $scope.getReactively( 'fileId' )
    fileObj = XmlFiles.findOne(fileId);
    if fileObj
      console.log("progress", fileObj.uploadProgress())

      if fileObj.hasStored('xmlFile')
        computation.stop();
        console.log("DOOONEEE")
```

This solution works perfectly for me and you DON'T NEED the CFS:UI package for this to work. All is in your CFS:FileSystem package.

Hope this was helpful for other people. Took my a couple of hours to puzzle it together.

Comment: Why downvote? It is related to the answer of @Ethaan but that is focusing on Blaze which doesn't work when you use Meteor + Angular. Hence my answer which does work for this situation

Comment: In Angular Meteor Environment your solution works just fine..in case anyone needed to display the progress of the upload..since the cfs-ui works within blaze and there is this problem of integrating blaze templates within angular after angular-meteor 1.3(https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/849) ...you can use this package(http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) ..it integrates seamlessly with Mattisj's answer

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working in a different manner setting a Meteor.setInterval that checks if the file is stored through fileObj.hasStored. It is not very elegant but it works.

```
'change .profile-photo': function(event, template) {

    var file = $('.profile-photo').get(0).files[0];
    var fileObj = Images.insert(file);
    var interval = Meteor.setInterval( function() {

             if (fileObj.hasStored('images')) {
                var imageURL = "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id;
                Meteor.call('updateUserProfilePhoto', imageURL, function (error, result) {
                  Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
                });
              }
    }, 50);

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for upload file (store S3) use angular and meteor (1.3.2) with progress bar:

Step 1:
Config and implement follow link: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/devel/packages/s3 (remember also add cfs:gridfs/cfs:filesystem because CollectionFS uses either the GridFS or FileSystem packages as a temporary store when uploading files to S3, so we need to include one of them and we’ve chosen GridFS).

Step 2: Subscribe images in controller (assume attachCtrl)

```
this.subscribe('images');
```

Step 3: Check progressing

```
this.helpers({
    progressing: () => {
      fileId = this.getReactively('currFileId');
      fileObj = Images.findOne({_id: fileId});
      if (fileObj) {
        if (fileObj instanceof FS.File) {
          return fileObj.uploadProgress();
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Step 4: Save image action

```
this.attachFile = (files) => {
    if(files.length > 0) {
      this.currFile = files[0];
      Images.insert(this.currFile, (err, fileObj) => {
        $scope.$apply(() => {
          this.currFileId = fileObj._id;
        });
      })
    }
  }
```

Step 5: Use progressing to display on progressing bar view.

```
<div class="progress progress-mini">
    <div style="width: {{attachCtrl.progressing}}%;" class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
```

Hope this was helpful for other people.