# Meteor: how to upload a file and then unzip it using fs file system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, meteor, zip

If we using CFS for meteor to upload large files online and when the storing (not uploading ) in done we have to trigger another event, say unzipping a file, then how will we do it ? isUpload is not appropriate in this case as file is not stored yet so unzipping won't work. What is the write say to do it on client side.

**JavaScript:**

```
var Zipper = new FS.Collection("zip", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("zip")]
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.upload.helpers({
    'data':function(){
      return Zipper.find(); 
    }
  });

  Template.upload.events({
    'change #fileUpload': function (event,template) {
      FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file) {
        var fileObj = new FS.File(file);
        var fileId;
        Zipper.insert(fileObj,function(err){
         });
      })
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    "unZipFile":function(fileId, fileName){
       //unzip the file using node package
    }
  });

}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>uploadAndZip</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
         {{> upload}}
    </div>


</body>

<template name="upload">
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload">  
    {{#each data}}
      {{#unless this.isUploaded}}
      {{> FS.UploadProgressBar bootstrap=true}}
      {{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each data}}
                <tr class="success">
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{size}} bytes</td>
                    <td>{{updatedAt}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

I tried to take help from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860545/is-there-any-event-to-indicate-that-the-uploaded-file-has-been-written-with-coll) but it's not helping.

Comment: why not just use transformWrite? https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#transformwrite--transformread

Comment: i used it. the unzip package(decompress-zip) i'm using giving error [Error: Offset is out of bounds]

Answer (score 0):

I've similar problem resolved using nodejs unzip and package: meteorhacks:npm.
Using on stored there's no need for a method, function will be executed when the zip is uploaded.

In this case I'm only extracting tif(f) and jpeg.

```
Zips.on('stored',  Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (fileObj) {

    var unzip = Meteor.npmRequire('unzip');
    var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
    fs.createReadStream(Meteor.settings.public.zipFolder+fileObj.copies.zip.key)
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on('entry', function (entry) {
            var fileName = entry.path;
            var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
            var size = entry.size;
            if (fileName.match(/(.tif+|.jpg|.jpeg)$/)) {
                console.log("extracting file: "+fileName);
                entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/'+fileName));
            } else {
                entry.autodrain();
            }
        });
}));
```